# I'm trying to make a drop down menu that opens windows with the same widgets but new ones added on as well

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new too python and StackOverflow so forgive me for how this looks.
I'm looking to make a calculator with tkinter and Python3, and I need to be able to open windows on click from an option menu that have some similar traits/widgets and some that are different. For example it starts on the basic calculator, but I can select another calculator from an OptionMenu that has the same numbers and operators but also adds new ones for trigonometry or geometry. What would be the best way to do this with classes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.
I think you should first implement the bone architecture first to make the whole implementation more simple.
In this case, the bone architecture of the original requirement is copying the window whilst giving formula in old window to the new window.
So, how about creating program which has only Entry and Button. If you push the button, a new cloned format window is opened and the Entry has the same text with the old window. like below:
[image]

Below is the sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


class WindowManager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_first_render = True

    def create_window(self, text):
        if self.is_first_render:
            master = root
            self.is_first_render = False
        else:
            master = tk.Toplevel(master=root)

        w = Window(master=master, text=text)


manager = WindowManager()


class Window():
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        e = tk.Entry(master=master)
        e.insert(0, text)
        e.pack()

        def clone():
            manager.create_window(text=e.get())

        b = tk.Button(
            master=master, text="Copy", command=clone)
        b.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.create_window(text="hello")
    root.mainloop()
```

To convert above to a calculator using the Menu and grid-style button, you just need to edit Window class.　　
To add the other button to the new window, you should create a new class by inheriting Window class.